# Python/Selenium Unknown error with .click()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

New to using selenium and have a little problem. I get this error when I try to use `.click()` on an element. Code is above it. And here is my website. https://www.minuteinbox.com/ Thanks for the help. If you need any more info just ask.

```
def get_email():
driver = webdriver.Edge('C:/Users/Aurum/Downloads/MicrosoftWebDriver')
driver.get("https://www.minuteinbox.com/")
assert "MinuteInbox" in driver.title
element_email = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
email = element_email.text
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
element_delete = driver.find_element_by_class_name('delete-tab')
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
element_delete.click()
driver.close()
return email
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Aurum\Documents\Programing\Prog 1\random stuff\FratThing.py", 
line 69, in main() File "C:\Users\Aurum\Documents\Programing\Prog 1\random stuff\FratThing.py", 
line 64, in main email = get_email() File "C:\Users\Aurum\Documents\Programing\Prog 1\random stuff\FratThing.py", 
line 14, in get_email element_delete.click() File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", 
line 80, in click self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT) File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", 
line 633, in _execute return self._parent.execute(command, params) File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", 
line 321, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", 
line 242, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error
```

Edit: So I figured out that the window has to be shrunk for it to work. If I make it bigger and change the class to fit the big button it does not work.

Edit2: Github Link https://github.com/WilPermenter/SignUpBot

Comment: You have chopped off the crucial error trace logs while shortening the log messages. Update the question with the error trace logs.

Comment: @DebanjanB That is exactly what pops up. Idk what ya mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the same with the below:

That is css selector

```
find_element_by_css_selector(".gradient .delete-tab").click()
```

This limits the matched elements to one

In your code:

```
except:
    element_delete = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gradient .delete-tab, .btn-delete')
    element_delete.click()
```

This should mean you can move this into the `try` instead as it already attempts to match on two selectors.

Comment: Yah I had that before and I was working. I had it working last night then I came back to it this morning and it was not working. I thought I had changed something in my code but I commented out everything but this function and It still is not working. I have the same problem with another button further down in the program. When I look at the css it no longer says .btn-delete. I know that the element is being selected because If i print the text it say delete. Thanks if ya have any more Ideals keep them coming.

Comment: I never got it to work with that. I basically just did what I had before and just made the window the size it works on. I am having the exact same problem with another btn. I might add that one to the post if I cant figure it out. Thx for the help

Comment: If screen size affects you should be able to use Or syntax of find_element_by_css_selector(".gradient .delete-tab, .btn-delete ").click()

Comment: So the email address is ok, to be able to create another email you need to delete the current one. Im getting them but still getting the same error even after adding ur code.

Comment: Im going to put the entire thing in a git hub and put the link in the OP. If you could look at that that might help. Iv changed it around but if you would It would be nice for you to put it the way you are talking about because I must not be doing it right.

Comment: Can I just confirm that with delete click I should see that email disappear from box and just be left with the email address printed out?

Comment: So it runs with my css selector in your except. See edit. I get the  result ['katerine', 'shawnee']

Comment: Any better at all?

Comment: So basicly with the first website all the btn does it take you do /delete off of that so I just force the website to go to that off the start to get a fresh email. Problem completely avoided and faster. But im haveing the same problme with the second website's "next" btn but that solution does not work for it.

Comment: There is a second part to this. I just had this problem first and thought I was having the same problem on the other website.Its on the github.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ill do a write up at the end that solved my problem. There were multiple elements that I thought I looked for but I missed one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Qharr answer and your question. Perhaps you should try to use seleniums `wait.until()`

```
from selenium import webdriver;
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("URLHERE")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"RELEVANT X PATH"))).click()
```

Perhaps waiting for the next button to be clicked until the driver can find it may help you.

If screen size is affecting you. You can try using `driver.set_window_size(480, 320)` after you have loaded your url with `driver.get("URL")` OF course you can set the window size to whatever works for you.